# jquery ~= works as =

Tags: jquery, html

I have a html code:

```
<input type='text' value='' name='cid' id='cid_id' action="_cidforsonum_unpaid" placeholder="Client" list="client_list">
```

now i am trying to read if `action` contains `_cidforsonum_`.

I have tried the following jquery code:

```
if($('input[name=cid][action~="_cidforsonum_"]').length>0){
console.log('hello mordekaiser!');
}
```

but it works, in my case, as `=`, since it worked for me when it was `action="_cidforsonum_"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [**^ attribute starts with selector**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value
>   beginning exactly with a given string.

```
if($('input[name=cid][action^="_cidforsonum_"]').length>0){
  console.log('hello mordekaiser!');
}
```

---

[**~ attribute contains word selector**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/)

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value
>   containing a given word, delimited by spaces.

**Your code not work as**

`_cidforsonum_unpaid` has no space after `_cidforsonum_`

`~` matches word delimited by spaces.

---

Updated after OP's comment.

Use [*** attribute contains selector**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

```
$('input[action*="_cidforsonum_"]')
```

Comment: thanks! it worked!! but since it works like that, I might have to remove all the underlines for shorter strings.

Comment: @FrancisXavierS.Antazo yeah but `^` is also good selector and `*` too .

Comment: I just checked how `*` works and saw it as a better fit to what I'm trying to accomplish. thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Try `^` instead of `~`

```
$('input[name=cid][action^="_cidforsonum_"]')
```

`^` selector select dom whoes attribute starts with.

**Comment Response**

You can do this using `*` selector.

**Example**

```
$( "input[action*='_cidforsonum_']" )
```

[**Official Doc**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

Comment: yes, but I need to check if it contains the string so I can just tag the actions for each element so I wont have to repeat each action for every element.